# XNA Sprite doesn't seem to be updating?

Tags: c#, xna, sprite, xna-4.0

I've looked through some other questions and haven't found my answer so I'm asking you lovely people as you have helped me before :)

I have a main class (RPG.cs) and a player class (Player.cs) and I want the Player class to be as self-contained as possible (because I don't want a huuuge main class) but here is my problem.

#### Problem

My Player sprite draws fine but when I want it to move, it won't update! At the moment I'm attempting to make it act like a cursor to test movement but eventually I'll have it bound to WASD or the arrow keys. So I want my sprite to follow my mouse at the moment but it just stays at 50, 50 (it's preset starting position) Have I missed something obvious? I'm new to XNA and I've spent half an hour on this problem!

**RPG.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace TestGame
{
    public class RPG : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        Texture2D PlayerTex;
        Rectangle playerPos = new Rectangle(
            Convert.ToInt32(Player.Pos.X), 
            Convert.ToInt32(Player.Pos.Y), 32, 32);
        public RPG()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
            IsMouseVisible = true;
        }
        protected override void Initialize() { base.Initialize(); }
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            PlayerTex = Content.Load<Texture2D>("testChar");
        }
        protected override void UnloadContent() { }
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if 
            (
                GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One)
                .Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed
            )
                this.Exit();
            base.Update(gameTime);
        }
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.White);
            spriteBatch.Begin();
            spriteBatch.Draw(PlayerTex, playerPos, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.End();
            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

**Player.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace TestGame
{
    /// This is a game component that implements IUpdateable.
    public class Player : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameComponent
    {
        public static Vector2 Pos = new Vector2(50, 50);
        MouseState ms = Mouse.GetState();
        public Player(Game game) : base(game) { }
        /// Allows the game component to perform 
        /// any initialization it needs to before 
        /// starting to run. This is where it can 
        /// query for any required services and load content.
        public override void Initialize() { base.Initialize(); }
        /// Allows the game component to update itself.
        public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            Pos.X = ms.X;
            Pos.Y = ms.Y;
            base.Update(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope you can help! :)

Comment: I think it's because you aren't calling the Update function of your player class in your main method.

Comment: @Haris I don't think so because in my main update function I typed 'Player.' and the Update function wasn't on the list. And when I use 'Player.Update(gameTime);' it gives me this: 'An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property.' and I can't change Update to static or more errors occur.

Comment: You obviously lack some basic knowledge of both OOP and XNA programming. An answer here cannot cover all problems of your code. I would advice to read about at least XNA's drawable components (e.g. [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1671634&seqNum=4)).

Comment: @NicoSchertler I am aware that I know little about this, but can you answer my question, not point out all the problems in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, I am not going to solve every problem. But the main errors.

Let the player be responsible for its position, not the game. Furthermore, I would make the player responsible for drawing itself, but that goes a bit too far for this answer.

The following code should at least work.

```
public class Player : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameComponent
{
    public Vector2 Pos { get; set; }

    public Player(Game game) : base(game)
    {
        this.Pos = new Vector2(50, 50);
    }

    public override void Initialize() { base.Initialize(); }

    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        var ms = Mouse.GetState();
        Pos.X = ms.X;
        Pos.Y = ms.Y;
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Then use the player in your game:

```
public class RPG : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Texture2D PlayerTex;

    Player player;

    public RPG()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        IsMouseVisible = true;
        player = new Player(this);
        Components.Add(player);
    }
    protected override void Initialize() { base.Initialize(); }
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        PlayerTex = Content.Load<Texture2D>("testChar");
    }
    protected override void UnloadContent() { }
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if 
        (
            GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One)
            .Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed
        )
            this.Exit();
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(PlayerTex, player.Pos, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

I have removed the texture's size. Don't know if you really need this. If so, you can let `Player` expose a Rectangle, not just a `Vector2`.

Answer (score 0):

The key solution which Nico included is just that you using the original rectangle coordinates you made when you draw:

```
Rectangle playerPos = new Rectangle(
             Convert.ToInt32(Player.Pos.X), 
             Convert.ToInt32(Player.Pos.Y), 32, 32);
```

Here you make the rectangle using the players CURRENT starting time position.
Then you ALWAYS draw based on this rectangle you made ages ago and never updated:

```
        spriteBatch.Draw(PlayerTex, playerPos, Color.White);
```

The right way as Nico mentioned is just to change the draw to this:

```
 playerPos = new Rectangle(
             Convert.ToInt32(Player.Pos.X), 
             Convert.ToInt32(Player.Pos.Y), 32, 32);

    spriteBatch.Draw(PlayerTex, playerPos, Color.White);
```

Now you will be drawing at a new place every time. There are better ways to do this (like what nico did) but here is the core idea.